# tabulator moveRow event destination parameter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I very rarely ask questions here since the overwhelming majority of the times I found ways to work around any problems. However this time I have a time shortage and lots of pressure.

Lately I started using tabulator and I have the best of impressions. However I got stambled into a simple yet important for me issue.

Tabulator offers the possibility of moving rows within a table and uses an event called rowMoved for handling. The function seems to have a single parameter (row) which is refered to the row that we wish to move. (There is an example about it)[text](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/move#rows). However it doesn't provide any parameter about the row (position/destination) that we want to move into. So my question is obvious. How can I get this info from the custom handler in order to use it for backend purposes?

I tried to use a second hidden parameter in the fucntion hoping that there is one and it is not referenced in the example but with no avail, the variable returned undefined.
e.g.

```
table.on("rowMoved", function(row, dest){
    console.log(dest);
});
```

I also tried to use rowMouseUp event but it messed up the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible workaround after searching a bit the "row" parameter object of the "rowMoved" function. I can get the new relative position of the row in the table through the row._row.position and I can proceed this way.